# Sister bought me out of house. What taxes do I owe?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ohio

My mom signed over her house five years ago for a dollar each. It was already paid off. My sister lived in it for the past five years. We agreed to sell it or she would buy me out at the five year mark since I live in another city. She ended up buying me out by taking a loan out on the house. Does this count as taxable income for me?

Comment: This cannot be answered with a location tag. Tax laws vary wildly around the globe.

Answer (score 2):

Your basis needs to be determined. Possibilities include:

- If you bought the house (or half the house) from non-relative the sale price would be the basis, unless you made additions/ improvements to the house. You would also account for the closing costs when determining the gains.
- If you inherited the house, it would be based on the value of the house when the person died. Again improvements/additions and closing costs would figure into the calculation.
- You were gifted the house. The basis would be the initial value of the house when the previous owner bought the house. This would of course have to factor in the improvements and additions by both the previous owner and you while you owned the house.
- The sale from a relative that was below market value would mean that the house had a gift aspect.  If the sale price was significantly below the value of the house, that delta would be a gift. That means that the basis is more complex.

according to the [IRS]:

> If the FMV of the property at the time the donor made the gift is less
> than the donor's adjusted basis, your adjusted basis depends on
> whether you have a gain or loss when you dispose of the property.
>
> - Your adjusted basis for figuring a gain is the donor's adjusted basis just before the donor made the gift, increased or decreased by
>   any required adjustments to basis while you held the property.
> - Your adjusted basis for figuring a loss is the FMV of the property at the time the donor made the gift, increased or decreased by any
>   required adjustments to basis while you held the property.
> - Note: If you use the donor's adjusted basis for figuring a gain and get a loss, and then use the FMV for figuring a loss and get a
>   gain, you have neither a gain nor loss on the sale or disposition of
>   the property.
>
> If the FMV of the property at the time the donor made the gift is
> equal to or greater than the donor's adjusted basis, your adjusted
> basis is the donor's adjusted basis just before the donor made the
> gift, increased or decreased by any required adjustments to basis
> while you held the property.

All this assumes that your sister wasn't paying you rent, which makes the calculation even more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You purchased an asset for X and sold it for Y, the difference Y-X is considered income. So whatever your sister paid you, minus the $1 you paid for your part of the house, is taxable income to you.

How this is treated depends on the tax laws of your country. In some countries there are different treatments for different types of income. For example, selling asset at a profit (like what you did) would be considered capital gains in the US if you're not in the business of buying and selling houses.

Comment: It may not even be treated as income. Maybe some countries would see the original sale at 1 dollar as a gift (and tax that) and treat the value of the ownership at fair market value. That would probably apply to The Netherlands (I'm not sure.... never encountered this). Best answer is... it depends on where you are.

Comment: @PaulPalmpje it's been five years, even if X is the fmv of the gift, Y is still probably higher anywhere where dollars are currency

Comment: correct but even then tax treatment could be very different. But I think we have to assume USA here and then I can't provide answers.

Comment: It would be better to not assume but ask for location. Tax questions are highly location dependent.

Comment: @Hilmar feel free to surprise me with a jurisdiction where the answer would be wrong. Also, feel free to surprise me with a money@SE question without a location tag that's not from the US.

Comment: It is Ohio , sorry for not including